# Image Files Management and Retrieval

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, image, picture-library

Seeking cautionary tales and guidance regarding images files stored in SP image library and filter by and retrieved to PA.

I inherited 3000+ .pdf files of all several different naming conventions.

I've given them all the same naming convention and converted them to .jpg.

I am prepared to upload them to an SP library, create connections to the library from PA, create a collection from which a condition in a Gallery will filter for the proper image(s).

Does anyone have any cautions or guidance regarding any of the above that will make my life easier, the upload and data management in SP and PS as efficient as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [this link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Image-Files-Management-and-Retrieval/td-p/755591) you posted, yes we could drag and drop them all from local drive to the document library with the modern experience.

In normal document library, you could also create multiple views with proeprty filter to manage them.